# Cultivation-based manhua about a protagonist who raids a dungeon with huge ants, and later develops a nation with a huge spirit tree

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I was reading this sci-fi/fantasy cultivation-based manhua (or manhwa, or manga), but I don't remember many things, except the following.

At the beginning, he talks to a super strong being that his soul is intertwined with or something, then he awakens and starts cultivation. He may have been used as monster bait by hunters. He also raids a dungeon with huge ants, and later develops a nation with a huge spirit tree, and invents spaceships.

If anyone can help me find this manhua, then thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the manga/manhwa/manhua you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I believe you might be looking for "I am the sorcerer king", although I don't remember him riding the ants. Are you certain that he did? Also, he talks to supreme being, but not in the beginning. Still, there was a similar episode that helped him start anew. Everything else matches perfectly fine.